# Jupyter notebook: DataFrame not printing as table

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

In my Jupyter notebook version 4.2.3, when I add a cell such as

```
products = pd.read_csv('products.csv') 
products.head()
len(products)
```

where products is a DataFrame, I expect a table to be displayed when the cell is run, as I have seen in other notebooks. But in order to display the DataFrame as a table, I have to first import the `display` method from `from IPython.display` and use `display(products.head())`, which works. What am I missing?

Comment: copy and paste the entire cell where this line is being run

Answer (score 1):

I caught my mistake. The last line in the cell is the one that's output. If I remove `len(products)` then the DataFrame prints as a table.